# Regex I copied into my Rails model won't work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Brand spanking new to Regex in Rails so please be gentle... I found the following on Regexlib.com to validate no spaces.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

But when I put it into

```
validates_format_of :first_name, :with => ^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

I get an error saying unexpected tCARET.  What's the problem?

Comment: Semi-OT: The regex you're using doesn't exactly validate no spaces, it validates "only ASCII letters". Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for a regex in Ruby is `/regex/`. So in your case `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`.